# Escape an apostrophe from a data binding's XML

Tags: html, xml, data-binding

I have a string from xml with an apostrophe that should be escaped to `&apos;` and it is not.

```
<city place="park's place"/>
```

In html I am grabbing the value.

```
<span datafld="place"></span>
```

I need the value in place to be "park`&apos;`s place" and not park's place. Currently it shows "park's place".

I have spent a good amount of time trying to find an answer and can't seem to find one.

This code example is badly hacked together since I am not allowed to show any original code.

Thanks.

Edit: This is on a xhtml page using javascript.

Comment: You don't tell us anything about what language, platform or APIs you're using. I'm not even sure what your problem is.

Comment: Why should it be escaped? That would give exactly the same data but with 5 extra bytes and less readability.

Comment: And if you have a `datafld` attribute, then you don't have XHTML.

Comment: It was assumed when the value came out of the oracle database that it would be escaped, the code matches the value with a `apos;` and not a '.

Comment: Textual content in the database shouldn't be XML-encoded, and you don't want `&apos;` in your page output because that's an XML-only predefined entity, it doesn't conform to browser HTML compatibility guidelines. I'm not sure what you're doing but I think you need to ensure that you're dealing with raw unescaped text at all times until the point you need to insert into HTML. (Which if you're using `datafld` without `dataformatas`, is already appropriately escaped.)

Answer (score 3):

In the XML "data model" all values are unescaped. So whether your attribute was specified as:

```
place="park's place"
```

or:

```
place="park&apos;s place"
```

or:

```
place="park&#39;s place"
```

when you use an XML parser (or the DOM) you'll get "park's place". (Things like "innerHTML" are an exception to this general rule.)

If you need to compare that to some other string that has a different level of escaping then you either need to escape the string you get from the DOM, or you need to unescape the other string. It's a lot like if you were going to compare a measurement in meters to one in feet: you need to convert to a common unit-of-measurement/level-of-escaping.

I'd go with the unescaping approach if you can. If that isn't possible then you'll need to make sure that you escape in a consistent way **everywhere**, which can be difficult. Note that I've shown you three different ways of legally escaping that particular string -- and there are many many more.

Comment: What you are saying is not happening on my side. I put "park`&apos;`s place into the database to form the XML and it still shows "park`&apos;`s place" in the span shown above. Either way I form the string, it comes out of the datafld just the same with no escaping or unescaping.

Comment: I'm talking about using DOM or SAX or something similar to read XML (I assume you're using the DOM, since you mentioned that you're using Javascript). Writing XML is a whole other thing. You haven't said what you're using to generate this XHTML, but in general you should be concerned about which characters are escaped in your XML, you should instead be using things like the DOM that will unescape them for you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it serves someone looking for it you can put the symbol (´) the tilde

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).